# Не выполняется метод в цикле

Tags: c#

Народ, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в общем мне нужно в цикле в отдельном потоке (перед этим подождав 10 сек) выполнить определенные действия, но чтобы цикл при этом не перескакивал через это. Пытаюсь выполнить (для примера) вот так:

```
private void Go()
{
    MessageBox.Show("длительный процесс выполняется");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("перед паузой");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Thread Process1 = new Thread(Go);//не выполняеться в цикле(              
        MessageBox.Show("после паузы");
    }        
}
```

Проскакивает через Go (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не знаю, зачем это всё, но вот то, что вы просите

```
    private void Go() {
        MessageBox.Show("длительный процесс выполняется");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        while (true) {
            MessageBox.Show("перед паузой");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Thread Process1 = new Thread(Go);  
            Process1.Start(); // запуск потока
            Process1.Join(); // ожидание завершения потока
            MessageBox.Show("после паузы");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! это похоже то что нужно. А я могу в потоках создавать другие потоки?

Comment: Никто не запрещает =)

Answer (score 3):

Вы Process1.Start не вызвали - так вы просто создаете экземпляры Thread'ов.